# How to dynamically update one json object and put it back into the original json objects variable using python3?

Tags: json, python-3.x

How to dynamically update one JSON object and put it back into the original JSON array variable using python3?

I have one variable with the following JSON data in it.

```
test='[
  {
    "Name": "James",
    "Mobile": 12345678,
    "Gender": "Male",
    "Boolean": true,
    "Pet": "cat"
  },
  {
    "Name": "John",
    "Mobile": 1234567875,
    "Gender": "Male",
    "Boolean": true,
    "Pet": "rat"
  },
  {
    "Name": "Jennifer",
    "Mobile": 1234567890,
    "Gender": "Female",
    "Boolean": true,
    "Pet": "Dog"
  },
  {
    "Name": "Julia",
    "Mobile": 1234567890,
    "Gender": "Female",
    "Boolean": true,
    "Pet": "Dog"
  },
  {
    "Name": "Jeff",
    "Mobile": 9871234567890,
    "Gender": "Male",
    "Boolean": true,
    "Pet": "Fish"
  },
  {
    "Name": "Jones",
    "Mobile": 79871234567890,
    "Gender": "Female",
    "Boolean": true,
    "Pet": "Parrot"
  }
]'
```

Now let's say we have the below second/any JSON object from the above JSON objects

```
{
  "Name": "John",
  "Mobile": 1234567875,
  "Gender": "Male",
  "Boolean": true,
  "Pet": "rat"
}
```

We have updated the above-picked JSON object fields with below

```
{
  "Name": "Sarah",
  "Mobile": 1234567875,
  "Gender":Female",
  "Boolean": true,
  "Pet": "rabbit"
}
```

Now how can we add/update the above modified JSON object back into the original objects list/array variable 'test' at the exact position (2nd position in this case) but using a filter of 'Name=John' and in a dynamic way (say we don't know exact index position of this object) using python3 scripting?

I have done the same thing in bash with jq map and filter operators, but don't know which functions/packages to use in python3 for this use-case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope I've understood your question right:

```py
import json

test='''[
  {
    "Name": "James",
    "Mobile": 12345678,
    "Gender": "Male",
    "Boolean": true,
    "Pet": "cat"
  },
  {
    "Name": "John",
    "Mobile": 1234567875,
    "Gender": "Male",
    "Boolean": true,
    "Pet": "rat"
  },
  {
    "Name": "Jennifer",
    "Mobile": 1234567890,
    "Gender": "Female",
    "Boolean": true,
    "Pet": "Dog"
  },
  {
    "Name": "Julia",
    "Mobile": 1234567890,
    "Gender": "Female",
    "Boolean": true,
    "Pet": "Dog"
  },
  {
    "Name": "Jeff",
    "Mobile": 9871234567890,
    "Gender": "Male",
    "Boolean": true,
    "Pet": "Fish"
  },
  {
    "Name": "Jones",
    "Mobile": 79871234567890,
    "Gender": "Female",
    "Boolean": true,
    "Pet": "Parrot"
  }
]'''

obj = '''{
  "Name": "Sarah",
  "Mobile": 1234567875,
  "Gender": "Female",
  "Boolean": true,
  "Pet": "rabbit"
}'''

# parse the test Json string
test = json.loads(test)

# parse the obj Json string
obj = json.loads(obj)

# replace object if name == 'John'
test = [obj if d['Name'] == 'John' else d for d in test]

# dump the test list back to Json
print(json.dumps(test, indent=4))
```

Prints:

```json
[
    {
        "Name": "James",
        "Mobile": 12345678,
        "Gender": "Male",
        "Boolean": true,
        "Pet": "cat"
    },
    {
        "Name": "Sarah",
        "Mobile": 1234567875,
        "Gender": "Female",
        "Boolean": true,
        "Pet": "rabbit"
    },
    {
        "Name": "Jennifer",
        "Mobile": 1234567890,
        "Gender": "Female",
        "Boolean": true,
        "Pet": "Dog"
    },
    {
        "Name": "Julia",
        "Mobile": 1234567890,
        "Gender": "Female",
        "Boolean": true,
        "Pet": "Dog"
    },
    {
        "Name": "Jeff",
        "Mobile": 9871234567890,
        "Gender": "Male",
        "Boolean": true,
        "Pet": "Fish"
    },
    {
        "Name": "Jones",
        "Mobile": 79871234567890,
        "Gender": "Female",
        "Boolean": true,
        "Pet": "Parrot"
    }
]
```